# How changes in sequences affect radius of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

I'm attempting to truly understand the radius of convergence.

Say I have a series $$\sum_{n=0} a_{n} x^n$$ with radius of convergence R. How do I describe, in terms of R, the radius of convergence of 
i) $$\sum_{n=0} a_{n}^p x^n$$
ii) $$\sum_{n=0} a_{n} x^{np} $$
In both cases, p is a natural number.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $ \lim \sup |a_n^p|^{1/n}=  (\lim \sup |a_n|^{1/n})^p$, hence the power series $\sum_{n=0} a_{n}^p x^n$ has radius of convergence $R^p$.

The series $\sum_{n=0} a_{n} x^{np}$ converges for $|x|^p <R$ and diverges for $|x|^p >R$. Therefore $\sum_{n=0} a_{n} x^{np}$ has radius of convergence $R^{1/p}$.